# Stable disk for $N$-body simulation

Tags: simulations, computational-physics, celestial-mechanics, many-body

I want to simulate a Galaxy of $N$ particles which I have to generate first. What I have done so fare does not lead to the result I want to see. I probably did an error and don't see it. Here comes what I did:

1) Generate uniformly distributed particles inside a unit circle with mass $m_i = 1/N$:

For every point I do:

```
   R = 1;
   radius = R*sqrt(rand(0,1));
   phi = rand(0,2*pi);
   m = 1/N;
   x = radius*cos(phi);
   y = radius*sin(phi);
```

Doing that I get the following distribution:

[image: t=0]

2) Generate velocities such that the circle does not explode or implode:

I want to generate something where $F_{\text{Gravity}} = F_{\text{Centrifugal}}$

Since $F_{\text{Centrifugal}} = \frac{mv^2}{r}$ and $F_{\text{Gravity}} = G\frac{M(r) m}{r^2}$ I can equate both equations and get for the velocity $v$

$M(r)$ is the mass inside radius $r$. I can write $M_{\text{tot}} = \pi R^2$ and $M=\pi r^2$ (density $\rho=1$). From those equations I get $M(r) = \frac{r^2}{R^2} M_{\text{tot}}$. I can now put it back to $v$ and get:

$v = \sqrt{\frac{Gr^2M_{\text{tot}}}{rR^2}}$

Since $M_{\text{tot}} = G = R = 1$ I get:

$v = \sqrt{r}$

So, for every point I do:

```
   velocity = sqrt(radius);
   v_x = -velocity*sin(phi);
   v_y = velocity*cos(phi);
```

Then I get the following result:

[image: t=1]

[image: t=4]

[image: t=7]
[image: t=10]

Ok, it seems that the circle explodes somehow. Particles from the center move outwards. Is my calculation for $v$ wrong, or does it simply not work for my purpose? Do I need another velocity distribution? In the end, for large $t$, I can't see any spiral arms forming or any other structure. I tried $N=4000$ and $N=50000$. Do I need more particles? Did I something wrong?

Comment: the `phi` for the velocities should be chosen randomly (uniform in $[0,2\pi)$).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I do that. I take the same `phi` I already take for the position of the particle. Is that wrong? Do I have to generate `phi` a second time for the velocity?

Comment: yes, that is wrong, and yes, you need to generate `phi` a second time for the velocity (try to think why!).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I don't see why I have to take another `phi`. This would mean, that the velocity is not tangential. And wouldn't that mean, that I would get a circle of randomly moving points instead of a rigid body rotation?

Comment: By taking the same `phi` both for position and velocities, you are making all velocities to be radial (i.e., no tangential component). This is the reason for the initial "outward explosion".

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform But than I have a "inward explosion" instead. Since the particles move randomly the 2D sphere collapses. There is no way that there can form a spiral structure. Or am I wrong? I just tested it with $N=3000$ and it looks like a star cluster without any structure.

Comment: If the distribution of $\phi_v$ is uniform, then the initial cluster has no angular momentum. You may want to try with non-uniform $\phi_v$.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic is correct, including the choice of tangential velocity as

```
 x = r*cos(phi);
 y = r*sin(phi);
 vx=-v*sin(phi);
 vy= v*cos(phi);
```

Where you (tried to) set `v` in centrifugal balance. However, the gravitational attraction of a disc is different from that of a sphere, in particular your assumption that the acceleration equals GM(r)/r^2 is wrong. The best way to find the correct form is to obtain the forces from your N-body model and take the azimuthal average of the radial acceleration in radial bins. Your initial model should satisfy **the virial theorem**, I.e. the kinetic energy should be -0.5 times the gravitational energy.

But how did you compute the forces and how did you integrate the equations of motion? You should avoid the exact N-body forces, because these diverge at close encounters and instead use **softened forces**. You essentially add for each particle-particle interaction a constant vertical offset `h`, the *softening length*. Set this to about 0.1 times the radius.

The time integration is best done using the leapfrog integrator. For example

```
for(I:particles)
    I.vel += 0.5*tau*I.acc
    I.pos += tau*I.vel
time += tau
compute_accelerations(particles);
for(I:particles)
    I.vel += 0.5*tau*I.acc
```

to integrate one time step of length `tau`. Of course, you must compute the initial accelerations before the first step. The step size `tau` should be small enough for the total energy to be conserved by one part in 1000 or better.

Comment: I used an tree algorithm with an Runge Kutta integrator. Is my approach correct if I use a sphere (3D)?

Comment: You can assign tangential velocities in equilibrium to particles in a sphere, but the sphere will not rotate and is not a disc. Did you use softening? How precisely did you decide when to open a cell with the tree code? -- perhaps you were not careful with that and ran into the "exploding galaxies bug"?

Comment: I already simulated a Plummer sphere and get good results. So I think there is an problem with the initial condition of the velocity. I tried your idea but get worse results. The sphere explodes. But at the very beginning there are some spiral arms visible! Maybe I did something wrong. Could you please carry out your idea and show how you would derive the right velocity for such a system? That would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately, you failed to provide sufficient information. How/what are the accelerations? How well are total energy, linear and angular momentum conserved????